# Looking for a free Geolocation Service (from Country/Prov/City) or Database?

Tags: web-services, geocoding

I am looking for a free service (providing a web service or a database that gets updated regularly) that will allow me to retrieve the Geolocations (Long/Lat) for Country/Prov/City.

Yahoo & Google's API's are unacceptable as they limit the total amount of requests DAILY.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm a fan of [Geolite](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location), they have both [city](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity) and [country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) databases, freely available [api](http://www.maxmind.com/app/api)'s in a number of languages and they update the databases on a fairly regular basis.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/)?

Comment: Geonames is great as a free resource.

Comment: Geonames was great except that they have separate city & postal databases that don't link together. i.e.: you end up with redundant data that cannot distinctly be associated to data in the other table.  For that reason, I switched to MaxMind's free Geolite databases.

Answer (score 1):

Try iopatch.com. It's also free and unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TIGER](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/) line data

EDIT: In my experience it's not as accurate as NAVTEQ data (i think google and yahoo use them) but its what you get for free.